# Updating an Environment in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, environment, interpreter, semantics

I'm taking some predefined semantic rules and implementing them as an interpreter for the lettuce language using Scala. In Multi-Let, I'm trying to update an environment variable using two lists. I'm sort of new to Scala so I'm not too sure how to do this without converting the environment variable to a List. Is there a way to manipulate the return type in my zip function? I'm getting the following error message. My goal is to get a single updated map rather than a list of updated maps.

```
cmd2.sc:44: type mismatch;
 found   : List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Helper.this.Value]]
 required: Helper.this.Environment
    (which expands to)  scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Helper.this.Value]
            evalExpr(e2,newEnv)
                        ^Compilation Failed
```

```
sealed trait Expr
case class Const(d: Double) extends Expr
case class Ident(s: String) extends Expr
case class Plus(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
case class Mult(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr 
case class Let(id: String, e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
case class MultiLet(id: List[String], eList: List[Expr], e2: Expr) extends Expr

sealed trait Value
case class NumValue(f: Double) extends Value
case object Error extends Value /* -- Do not return Error -- simply throw an new IllegalArgumentException whenever you encounter an erroneous case --*/

type Environment = Map[String, Value]

def evalExpr(e: Expr, env: Environment): Value = {
    
    e match {
       
        case Let(x, e1, e2) => {
            val v1 = evalExpr(e1, env) 
            val newEnv = env.updated(x,v1);
            evalExpr(e2,newEnv)
        }

        case MultiLet(xList, eList, e2) => {
            val vList = eList.map(evalExpr(_, env))
            val newEnv = (xList, vList).zipped.map{ (x, v) => env.updated(x,v)}
            println(newEnv)
            evalExpr(e2,newEnv)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you wanted to either `foldLeft(env) { case (e, (x, y)) => e.updated(x, y) }`, or simply put all values with `++`. 

But I think it wouldn't work correctly: `eList.map(evalExpr(_, env))` would evaluate all the right hand sides in the old environment, but you need the updated environment for all the mutually recursive definitions to work, don't you?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin that is correct. I might have gotten that part incorrect. It was a recommendation from an old question. I was going to get ```case MultiLet ``` done first and then compile the whole thing against my pre built test cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that we are dealing the case of `Const` the following way:

```
case Const(d) => NumValue(d)
```

In order to get an updated environment, you need to use `foldLedt`:

```
val newEnv = (xList, vList).zipped.foldLeft(env) { (e, kv) =>
  e.updated(kv._1, kv._2)
}
```

Let's now test it:

When starting the program, the environment is empty, so we are running with an empty map:

```
evalExpr(MultiLet(List("1", "2"), List(Const(4), Const(5)), Const(6)), Map.empty)
```

The output is:

```
Map(1 -> NumValue(4.0), 2 -> NumValue(5.0))
```

Then, we get to a function where do not yet have conflicts:

```
evalExpr(MultiLet(List("2"), List(Const(5)), Const(6)), Map("1" -> NumValue(7)))
```

The output is:

```
Map(1 -> NumValue(4.0), 2 -> NumValue(7.0))
```

And the last case is when we have conflicting variables:

```
evalExpr(MultiLet(List("1", "2"), List(Const(4), Const(5)), Const(6)), Map("1" -> NumValue(7)))`
```

Which outputs:

```
Map(1 -> NumValue(4.0), 2 -> NumValue(5.0))
```

Code snippet can be found at [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/spcOSa8HTn69hk1ZR8KWlQ).

Comment: You're the man. Everything worked out perfectly. I'm not sure I would have gotten that correct. I don't understand why updating e works instead of updating env, similar to what is done in ```case Let ```